# How to call one service from another in angular 6

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, angular-services

In below code, I have this Service 1 : uploadAttachment method which is actually making http post call and this method (uploadAttachment) is getting called from another Service 2. In Service 2, I always get the instance of service 1 undefined. So, call failed to Service 1.

Service 1:

```js
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class Service1 {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  uploadAttachments(formData: any): any {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data');
    headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');

    return  this.http.post(this.baseURL + 'Data/UpdateInsertAttachments', formData,
    {headers: headers});
  }
}
```

Service 2:

```js
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class Service2 {
  constructor(private service: Service1) {

  fileChange(event) {
    const formData: FormData = new FormData();
    // some code
    this.service.uploadAttachments(formData).subscribe(
      resp => {
        if (resp === -1 ) {
            alert('Error occured while uploading the attachment');
            return;
        } else {
            // some code
        }
      },
      (error) => {
        console.log('POST ERROR in method uploadAttachments: ' + error.error);
      });
  }
}
```

Comment: Many things can be happening to cause this error. For example, Service1 may be contained in a lazy loaded module that is not loaded yet when Service2 requests it.

Answer (score 0):

Since Service1 expects a HttpClient in it's Signature, you have to provide this one to it

Comment: u mean to inject HttpClient in Service 2 also?